# Objects are not valid as a React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, javascript-objects

I am not sure why I am getting this error, my first loop is working fine as I am able to print out the values but the 2nd loop it keeps pulling this error. I have tried changing to a regular map, but that errors out too. Not sure what is going on in the 2nd loop.

```
  const TableRows = (rows) => {
    const row = Object.entries(rows).map((owner, mainIndex) => {
      return (
        <TableRow key={console.log(`row-record-${owner[0]}`)} highlightOnHover={true}>
          {Object.entries(owner).map((value, index) =>  (
            <TableCell
              key={`column-value-${value}`}
              alignmentHorizontal={
                tabsAlignment[props.metricComponent] &&
                props.componentName != "Open_COE_Default"
                  ? tabsAlignment[props.metricComponent][index]
                  : index != 0
                    ? "center"
                    : ""
              }
              sortColumn={value}
            >

              {loadData(value, index, owner, mainIndex)}
            </TableCell>
          ))}
        </TableRow>
      );
    });
    return row;
  };
```

EDIT:

This is how loadData is working

```
 const loadData = (value, index, ownerData, mainIndex) => {
    {console.log("Test" + value[index])}
    if (
      isNotNullOrUndefined(props.componentName) &&
      props.componentName == "Open_COE_Default"
    ) {
      if (value > 0 && index >= 1) {
        return (
          <Link
            href="#"
            type="secondary"
            onClick={() => {
              loadRawData(index, ownerData[0]);
            }}
          >
            {console.log("Value " + value)}
            {value}
          </Link>
        );
      } else if (index == 0) {
        return (
          <div
            style={{
              marginLeft:
                !pathname.includes(routes.WBR) && mainIndex != 0
                  ? OWNER_RECORD_MARGIN
                  : null,
            }}
          >
            <Link
              href="#"
              type="secondary"
              onClick={() => {
                updateUserChain(ownerData[0]);
              }}
            >
              {ownerData[0]}
            </Link>
          </div>
        );
      } else {
        return value;
      }
```

Comment: Can you show how loadData is working? Does it return a valid JSX?

Comment: Added Load data to the question

Comment: isn't `value` (see `return value;` near the end)...an object?

Comment: @ZubairAmjad even in the modified code we can't see where exactly you are returning an Object. But all the error is saying is that you are, in some component, returning an Object in the JSX instead of a value, and React can't render an Object.